# Using a react component from npm with reactjs.net

Tags: asp.net-core, reactjs.net

How can I add a react component from `npm` to my `Startup.cs`?

For [their demo that I followed](http://reactjs.net/getting-started/aspnet5.html), I currently have:

```
app.UseReact(config =>
{
    config.AddScript("~/js/helloworld.jsx");
});
```

and this works fine.

If I have a component that I've installed via `npm`, that resides in the `node_modules` folder, how can I reference and use this to serverside render with `Reactjs.NET`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this based on the `reactnet-webpack` template. In my case I was trying to include `react-jsonschema-form`, but I guess it should work the same for all other React components.

1. Install component `npm install -s @rjsf/core`
2. Import in your .jsx file where you'd like to use the component: `import Form from "@rjsf/core";`
3. Add component inside an existing render function:

```js
const schema = {
    title: "Todo",
    type: "object",
    required: ["title"],
    properties: {
        title: { type: "string", title: "Title", default: "A new task" },
        done: { type: "boolean", title: "Done?", default: false }
    }
};
const log = (type) => console.log.bind(console, type);

render() {
    return (                
        <Form schema={schema}
              onChange={log("changed")}
              onSubmit={log("submitted")}
              onError={log("errors")} />
        );
    }
}
```

4. **Rebuild JS parts using Webpack: `npm run build`**
5. Start app in Visual Studio